# Can't get ruby 1.9.3 installed on OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby, macos, osx-mountain-lion, octopress

I have home brew installed and rbenv. I've followed these instructions:

http://octopress.org/docs/setup/rbenv/

Everything seems to work flawlessly but when I type

> ruby -v

it still says 1.8.7...

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried opening a new shell to make sure all the shell configuration is resourced?

Comment: I have my own custom bashrc with a profile, env and config files. I bet when I'm installing it isn't getting put in the right place.. I don't see rbenv in my path, but it still works when I type it into the shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unix will run the copy of Ruby that it finds first in your search path. Type these commands in Terminal:

```
echo $PATH
which ruby
```

The first will show you the order in which Unix is looking for the `ruby` command. The second will tell you which `ruby` it's finding. You may need to edit the `PATH=` command in your .bash_profile or .bashrc to change the order of the search path, e.g.:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```

prepends /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/sbin to your existing PATH to tell Unix to search your /usr/local/bin directory before /usr/bin

Comment: which ruby is /usr/bin/ruby and its still 1.8.7. I'm on OSX, not sure I have sbin

Comment: Ok here it is. ~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby. So I just need to add that directory to my path? Will it overwrite the usr/bin/ruby ?

Comment: I added it to my env file and sourced it, but ruby -v still says 1.8.7

Comment: nevermind I got it. My alias was typed wrong but it didn't throw an error. Ruby -v now says 1.9.3.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org) and [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/) many times the last couple of years. When it comes to ruby no other system can match [RVM](https://rvm.io/).

There are numerous guides online. Google, pick one and go.

NOTE: *Octopress bloging system, comes with an rvm-ready bundle which will install and use ruby-1.9.2x, last time I checked :-)*

Comment: Yea I have both installed... hope that doesn't mess me up

Comment: Both meaning? Homebrew and Macports? If that's the case, it will surely mess you up in the long run...

Comment: Why do you need rbenv for? RVM handles all possible tasks just fine.